# Longtables Help

Tags: tables, tabularx, arrays

I want to resize my table for the Appendices in our paper. But I don't know how. Please help me revise it, the output of the table is just half of the paper. Thank you!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,epsfig,hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx,array,float,longtable,multicol,bigstrut}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|c|c|c|@{}}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
W(3,n) & v(1,1) & v(1,2) & v(1,3) & v(2,1) & v(2,2) & v(2,3) & v(3,1) & v(3,2) & v(3,3) & v(4,1) & v(4,2) & v(4,3) & v(5,1) & v(5,2) & v(5,3) & v(6,1) & v(6,2) & v(6,3) & v(7,1) & v(7,2) & v(7,3) & v(8,1) & v(8,2) & v(8,3) & v(9,1) & v(9,2) & v(9,3) & v(10,1) & v(10,2) & v(10,3) \\
\hline
W(3,1) & 2 & 4 & 6 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
W(3,2) & 2 & 4 & 6 & 3 & 5 & 7 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
W(3,3) & 2 & 5 & 8 & 3 & 6 & 9 & 4 & 7 & 10 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
W(3,4) & 2 & 6 & 10 & 3 & 7 & 11 & 4 & 8 & 12 & 5 & 9 & 13 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
W(3,5) & 2 & 7 & 12 & 3 & 8 & 13 & 4 & 9 & 14 & 5 & 10 & 15 & 6 & 11 & 16 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
W(3,6) & 2 & 8 & 14 & 3 & 9 & 15 & 4 & 10 & 16 & 5 & 11 & 17 & 6 & 12 & 18 & 7 & 13 & 19 & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
W(3,7) & 2 & 9 & 16 & 3 & 10 & 17 & 4 & 11 & 18 & 5 & 12 & 19 & 6 & 13 & 20 & 7 & 14 & 21 & 8 & 15 & 22 & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
W(3,8) & 2 & 10 & 18 & 3 & 11 & 19 & 4 & 12 & 20 & 5 & 13 & 21 & 6 & 14 & 22 & 7 & 15 & 23 & 8 & 16 & 24 & 9 & 17 & 25 & & & & & &\\
\hline
W(3,9) & 2 & 11 & 20 & 3 & 12 & 21 & 4 & 13 & 22 & 5 & 14 & 23 & 6 & 15 & 24 & 7 & 16 & 25 & 8 & 17 & 26 & 9 & 18 & 27 & 10 & 19 & 28 & & &\\
\hline
W(3,10) & 2 & 12 & 22 & 3 & 13 & 23 & 4 & 14 & 24 & 5 & 15 & 25 & 6 & 16 & 26 & 7 & 17 & 27 & 8 & 18 & 28 & 9 & 19 & 29 & 10 & 20 & 30 & 11 & 21 & 31\\
\hline
W(3,11) & 2 & 13 & 24 & 3 & 14 & 25 & 4 & 15 & 26 & 5 & 16 & 27 & 6 & 17 & 28 & 7 & 18 & 29 & 8 & 19 & 30 & 9 & 20 & 31 & 10 & 21 & 32 & 11 & 22 & 33\\
\hline
W(3,12) & 2 & 14 & 26 & 3 & 15 & 27 & 4 & 16 & 28 & 5 & 17 & 29 & 6 & 18 & 30 & 7 & 19 & 31 & 8 & 20 & 32 & 9 & 21 & 33 & 10 & 22 & 34 & 11 & 23 & 35\\
\hline
W(3,13) & 2 & 15 & 28 & 3 & 16 & 29 & 4 & 17 & 30 & 5 & 18 & 31 & 6 & 19 & 32 & 7 & 20 & 33 & 8 & 21 & 34 & 9 & 22 & 35 & 10 & 23 & 36 & 11 & 24 & 37\\
\hline
W(3,14) & 2 & 16 & 30 & 3 & 17 & 31 & 4 & 18 & 32 & 5 & 19 & 33 & 6 & 20 & 34 & 7 & 21 & 35 & 8 & 22 & 36 & 9 & 23 & 37 & 10 & 24 & 38 & 11 & 25 & 39\\
\hline
W(3,15) & 2 & 17 & 32 & 3 & 18 & 33 & 4 & 19 & 34 & 5 & 20 & 35 & 6 & 21 & 36 & 7 & 22 & 37 & 8 & 23 & 38 & 9 & 24 & 39 & 10 & 25 & 40 & 11 & 26 & 41\\
\hline
W(3,16) & 2 & 18 & 34 & 3 & 19 & 35 & 4 & 20 & 36 & 5 & 21 & 37 & 6 & 22 & 38 & 7 & 23 & 39 & 8 & 24 & 40 & 9 & 25 & 41 & 10 & 26 & 42 & 11 & 27 & 43\\
\hline
W(3,17) & 2 & 19 & 36 & 3 & 20 & 37 & 4 & 21 & 38 & 5 & 22 & 39 & 6 & 23 & 40 & 7 & 24 & 41 & 8 & 25 & 42 & 9 & 26 & 43 & 10 & 27 & 44 & 11 & 28 & 45\\
\hline
W(3,18) & 2 & 20 & 38 & 3 & 21 & 39 & 4 & 22 & 40 & 5 & 23 & 41 & 6 & 24 & 42 & 7 & 25 & 43 & 8 & 26 & 44 & 9 & 27 & 45 & 10 & 28 & 46 & 11 & 29 & 47\\
\hline
W(3,19) & 2 & 21 & 40 & 3 & 22 & 41 & 4 & 23 & 42 & 5 & 24 & 43 & 6 & 25 & 44 & 7 & 26 & 45 & 8 & 27 & 46 & 9 & 28 & 47 & 10 & 29 & 48 & 11 & 30 & 49\\
\hline
W(3,20) & 2 & 22 & 42 & 3 & 23 & 43 & 4 & 24 & 44 & 5 & 25 & 45 & 6 & 26 & 46 & 7 & 27 & 47 & 8 & 28 & 48 & 9 & 29 & 49 & 10 & 30 & 50 & 11 & 31 & 51\\
\hline
W(3,21) & 2 & 23 & 44 & 3 & 24 & 45 & 4 & 25 & 46 & 5 & 26 & 47 & 6 & 27 & 48 & 7 & 28 & 49 & 8 & 29 & 50 & 9 & 30 & 51 & 10 & 31 & 52 & 11 & 32 & 53\\
\hline
W(3,22) & 2 & 24 & 46 & 3 & 25 & 47 & 4 & 26 & 48 & 5 & 27 & 49 & 6 & 28 & 50 & 7 & 29 & 51 & 8 & 30 & 52 & 9 & 31 & 53 & 10 & 32 & 54 & 11 & 33 & 55\\
\hline
W(3,23) & 2 & 25 & 48 & 3 & 26 & 49 & 4 & 27 & 50 & 5 & 28 & 51 & 6 & 29 & 52 & 7 & 30 & 53 & 8 & 31 & 54 & 9 & 32 & 55 & 10 & 33 & 56 & 11 & 34 & 57\\
\hline
W(3,24) & 2 & 26 & 50 & 3 & 27 & 51 & 4 & 28 & 52 & 5 & 29 & 53 & 6 & 30 & 54 & 7 & 31 & 55 & 8 & 32 & 56 & 9 & 33 & 57 & 10 & 34 & 58 & 11 & 35 & 59 \\
\hline
W(3,25) & 2 & 27 & 52 & 3 & 28 & 53 & 4 & 29 & 54 & 5 & 30 & 55 & 6 & 31 & 56 & 7 & 32 & 57 & 8 & 33 & 58 & 9 & 34 & 59 & 10 & 35 & 60 & 11 & 36 & 61\\
\hline
W(3,26) & 2 & 28 & 54 & 3 & 29 & 55 & 4 & 30 & 56 & 5 & 31 & 57 & 6 & 32 & 58 & 7 & 33 & 59 & 8 & 34 & 60 & 9 & 35 & 61 & 10 & 36 & 62 & 11 & 37 & 63\\
\hline
W(3,27) & 2 & 29 & 56 & 3 & 30 & 57 & 4 & 31 & 58 & 5 & 32 & 59 & 6 & 33 & 60 & 7 & 34 & 61 & 8 & 35 & 62 & 9 & 36 & 63 & 10 & 37 & 64 & 11 & 38 & 65\\
\hline
W(3,28) & 2 & 30 & 58 & 3 & 31 & 59 & 4 & 32 & 60 & 5 & 33 & 61 & 6 & 34 & 62 & 7 & 35 & 63 & 8 & 36 & 64 & 9 & 37 & 65 & 10 & 38 & 66 & 11 & 39 & 67\\
\hline
W(3,29) & 2 & 31 & 60 & 3 & 32 & 61 & 4 & 33 & 62 & 5 & 34 & 63 & 6 & 35 & 64 & 7 & 36 & 65 & 8 & 37 & 66 & 9 & 38 & 67 & 10 & 39 & 68 & 11 & 40 & 69\\
\hline
W(3,30) & 2 & 32 & 62 & 3 & 33 & 63 & 4 & 34 & 64 & 5 & 35 & 65 & 6 & 36 & 66 & 7 & 37 & 67 & 8 & 38 & 68 & 9 & 39 & 69 & 10 & 40 & 70 & 11 & 41 & 71\\
\hline
W(3,31) & 2 & 33 & 64 & 3 & 34 & 65 & 4 & 35 & 66 & 5 & 36 & 67 & 6 & 37 & 68 & 7 & 38 & 69 & 8 & 39 & 70 & 9 & 40 & 71 & 10 & 41 & 72 & 11 & 42 & 73\\
\hline
W(3,32) & 2 & 34 & 66 & 3 & 35 & 67 & 4 & 36 & 68 & 5 & 37 & 69 & 6 & 38 & 70 & 7 & 39 & 71 & 8 & 40 & 72 & 9 & 41 & 73 & 10 & 42 & 74 & 11 & 43 & 75\\
\hline
W(3,33) & 2 & 35 & 68 & 3 & 36 & 69 & 4 & 37 & 70 & 5 & 38 & 71 & 6 & 39 & 72 & 7 & 40 & 73 & 8 & 41 & 74 & 9 & 42 & 75 & 10 & 43 & 76 & 11 & 44 & 77\\
\hline
W(3,34) & 2 & 36 & 70 & 3 & 37 & 71 & 4 & 38 & 72 & 5 & 39 & 73 & 6 & 40 & 74 & 7 & 41 & 75 & 8 & 42 & 76 & 9 & 43 & 77 & 10 & 44 & 78 & 11 & 45 & 79\\
\hline
W(3,35) & 2 & 37 & 72 & 3 & 38 & 73 & 4 & 39 & 74 & 5 & 40 & 75 & 6 & 41 & 76 & 7 & 42 & 77 & 8 & 43 & 78 & 9 & 44 & 79 & 10 & 45 & 80 & 11 & 46 & 81\\
\hline
W(3,36) & 2 & 38 & 74 & 3 & 39 & 75 & 4 & 40 & 76 & 5 & 41 & 77 & 6 & 42 & 78 & 7 & 43 & 79 & 8 & 44 & 80 & 9 & 45 & 81 & 10 & 46 & 82 & 11 & 47 & 83\\
\hline
W(3,37) & 2 & 39 & 76 & 3 & 40 & 77 & 4 & 41 & 78 & 5 & 42 & 79 & 6 & 43 & 80 & 7 & 44 & 81 & 8 & 45 & 82 & 9 & 46 & 83 & 10 & 47 & 84 & 11 & 48 & 85\\
\hline
W(3,38) & 2 & 40 & 78 & 3 & 41 & 79 & 4 & 42 & 80 & 5 & 43 & 81 & 6 & 44 & 82 & 7 & 45 & 83 & 8 & 46 & 84 & 9 & 47 & 85 & 10 & 48 & 86 & 11 & 49 & 87\\
\hline
W(3,39) & 2 & 41 & 80 & 3 & 42 & 81 & 4 & 43 & 82 & 5 & 44 & 83 & 6 & 45 & 84 & 7 & 46 & 85 & 8 & 47 & 86 & 9 & 48 & 87 & 10 & 49 & 88 & 11 & 50 & 89\\
\hline
W(3,40) & 2 & 42 & 82 & 3 & 43 & 83 & 4 & 44 & 84 & 5 & 45 & 85 & 6 & 46 & 86 & 7 & 47 & 87 & 8 & 48 & 88 & 9 & 49 & 89 & 10 & 50 & 90 & 11 & 51 & 91\\
\hline
W(3,41) & 2 & 43 & 84 & 3 & 44 & 85 & 4 & 45 & 86 & 5 & 46 & 87 & 6 & 47 & 88 & 7 & 48 & 89 & 8 & 49 & 90 & 9 & 50 & 91 & 10 & 51 & 92 & 11 & 52 & 93\\
\hline
W(3,42) & 2 & 44 & 86 & 3 & 45 & 87 & 4 & 46 & 88 & 5 & 47 & 89 & 6 & 48 & 90 & 7 & 49 & 91 & 8 & 50 & 92 & 9 & 51 & 93 & 10 & 52 & 94 & 11 & 53 & 95\\
\hline
W(3,43) & 2 & 45 & 88 & 3 & 46 & 89 & 4 & 47 & 90 & 5 & 48 & 91 & 6 & 49 & 92 & 7 & 50 & 93 & 8 & 51 & 94 & 9 & 52 & 95 & 10 & 53 & 96 & 11 & 54 & 97\\
\hline
W(3,44) & 2 & 46 & 90 & 3 & 47 & 91 & 4 & 48 & 92 & 5 & 49 & 93 & 6 & 50 & 94 & 7 & 51 & 95 & 8 & 52 & 96 & 9 & 53 & 97 & 10 & 54 & 98 & 11 & 55 & 99\\
\hline
W(3,45) & 2 & 47 & 92 & 3 & 48 & 93 & 4 & 49 & 94 & 5 & 50 & 95 & 6 & 51 & 96 & 7 & 52 & 97 & 8 & 53 & 98 & 9 & 54 & 99 & 10 & 55 & 100 & 11 & 56 & 101\\
\hline
W(3,46) & 2 & 48 & 94 & 3 & 49 & 95 & 4 & 50 & 96 & 5 & 51 & 97 & 6 & 52 & 98 & 7 & 53 & 99 & 8 & 54 & 100 & 9 & 55 & 101 & 10 & 56 & 102 & 11 & 57 & 103\\
\hline
W(3,47) & 2 & 49 & 96 & 3 & 50 & 97 & 4 & 51 & 98 & 5 & 52 & 99 & 6 & 53 & 100 & 7 & 54 & 101 & 8 & 55 & 102 & 9 & 56 & 103 & 10 & 57 & 104 & 11 & 58 & 105\\
\hline
W(3,48) & 2 & 50 & 98 & 3 & 51 & 99 & 4 & 52 & 100 & 5 & 53 & 101 & 6 & 54 & 102 & 7 & 55 & 103 & 8 & 56 & 104 & 9 & 57 & 105 & 10 & 58 & 106 & 11 & 59 & 107\\
\hline
W(3,49) & 2 & 51 & 100 & 3 & 52 & 101 & 4 & 53 & 102 & 5 & 54 & 103 & 6 & 55 & 104 & 7 & 56 & 105 & 8 & 57 & 106 & 9 & 58 & 107 & 10 & 59 & 108 & 11 & 60 & 109\\
\hline
W(3,50) & 2 & 52 & 102 & 3 & 53 & 103 & 4 & 54 & 104 & 5 & 55 & 105 & 6 & 56 & 106 & 7 & 57 & 107 & 8 & 58 & 108 & 9 & 59 & 109 & 10 & 60 & 110 & 11 & 61 & 111\\
\hline
W(3,51) & 2 & 53 & 104 & 3 & 54 & 105 & 4 & 55 & 106 & 5 & 56 & 107 & 6 & 57 & 108 & 7 & 58 & 109 & 8 & 59 & 110 & 9 & 60 & 111 & 10 & 61 & 112 & 11 & 62 & 113\\
\hline
W(3,52) & 2 & 54 & 106 & 3 & 55 & 107 & 4 & 56 & 108 & 5 & 57 & 109 & 6 & 58 & 110 & 7 & 59 & 111 & 8 & 60 & 112 & 9 & 61 & 113 & 10 & 62 & 114 & 11 & 63 & 115\\
\hline
W(3,53) & 2 & 55 & 108 & 3 & 56 & 109 & 4 & 57 & 110 & 5 & 58 & 111 & 6 & 59 & 112 & 7 & 60 & 113 & 8 & 61 & 114 & 9 & 62 & 115 & 10 & 63 & 116 & 11 & 64 & 117\\
\hline
W(3,54) & 2 & 56 & 110 & 3 & 57 & 111 & 4 & 58 & 112 & 5 & 59 & 113 & 6 & 60 & 114 & 7 & 61 & 115 & 8 & 62 & 116 & 9 & 63 & 117 & 10 & 64 & 118 & 11 & 65 & 119\\
\hline
W(3,55) & 2 & 57 & 112 & 3 & 58 & 113 & 4 & 59 & 114 & 5 & 60 & 115 & 6 & 61 & 116 & 7 & 62 & 117 & 8 & 63 & 118 & 9 & 64 & 119 & 10 & 65 & 120 & 11 & 66 & 121\\
\hline
W(3,56) & 2 & 58 & 114 & 3 & 59 & 115 & 4 & 60 & 116 & 5 & 61 & 117 & 6 & 62 & 118 & 7 & 63 & 119 & 8 & 64 & 120 & 9 & 65 & 121 & 10 & 66 & 122 & 11 & 67 & 123\\
\hline
W(3,57) & 2 & 59 & 116 & 3 & 60 & 117 & 4 & 61 & 118 & 5 & 62 & 119 & 6 & 63 & 120 & 7 & 64 & 121 & 8 & 65 & 122 & 9 & 66 & 123 & 10 & 67 & 124 & 11 & 68 & 125\\
\hline
W(3,58) & 2 & 60 & 118 & 3 & 61 & 119 & 4 & 62 & 120 & 5 & 63 & 121 & 6 & 64 & 122 & 7 & 65 & 123 & 8 & 66 & 124 & 9 & 67 & 125 & 10 & 68 & 126 & 11 & 69 & 127\\
\hline
W(3,59) & 2 & 61 & 120 & 3 & 62 & 121 & 4 & 63 & 122 & 5 & 64 & 123 & 6 & 65 & 124 & 7 & 66 & 125 & 8 & 67 & 126 & 9 & 68 & 127 & 10 & 69 & 128 & 11 & 70 & 129\\
\hline
W(3,60) & 2 & 62 & 122 & 3 & 63 & 123 & 4 & 64 & 24 & 5 & 65 & 125 & 6 & 66 & 126 & 7 & 67 & 127 & 8 & 68 & 128 & 9 & 69 & 128 & 10 & 70 & 130 & 11 & 71 & 131\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{longtable} 
\begin{center}
\normalsize\textbf{Table 1. $L(2,1)$-labeling of each vertex in \\ triangular windmill graph}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you nesting a `tabular` environment in a `longtable`?

Comment: What kind of information are you trying to convey by printing a table with 31 [!!] columns? Do you even remotely expect anyone to glance at such a table for more than two seconds?

Comment: Don't use \resizebox for tables: it leads to inconsistent fontsizes. Change the fon,tsize to, say, `\footnotesize` and play with the value of `\tabcolsep` (default is 2×6pt). But I doubt that with so many column, it can fit on a page width. Maybe in landscape orientation...

Comment: @Mico: You have actually counted the number of columns? I was too lazy for that

Comment: @Bernard `\tiny` and `\tabcolsep=1pt` aren't remotely enough.

Comment: table is so wide that with `tiny` font size and `\tabcolsize=0pt` can not be fit on page in `landscape` orientation. from `latex` point of view you should split table (at least) on two parts. before this consider @Mico first comment!

Answer (score 5):

- considered page layout as proposed [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) in his answer
- for landscape orientation used `pdflscape` package
- reorganized columns headers allows font size `\small`
- since table after that measures occupy two pages, the `longtable` is used

result:

[image]
[image]

mwe:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page dimensions
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{}}{#1}}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\captionsetup{font=small}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                     l
                *{9}{S[table-format=1.0]
                     S[table-format=2.0]
                     S[table-format=2.1]}
                     S[table-format=2.0]
                     S[table-format=2.0]
                     S[table-format=2.0]
                    }
    \caption{$L(2,1)$-labeling of each vertex in triangular windmill graph}
    \label{tab: my huge table}  \\
\toprule
    & \mc{v(1,i)}   & \mc{v(2,i)}   & \mc{v(3,i)}   & \mc{v(4,i)}
    & \mc{v(5,i)}   & \mc{v(6,i)}   & \mc{v(7,i)}   & \mc{v(8,i)}
    & \mc{v(9,i)}   & \mc{v(10,i)}                      \\
    \cmidrule{2-4}  \cmidrule{5-7}  \cmidrule{8-10} \cmidrule{11-13}
    \cmidrule{14-16}\cmidrule{17-19}\cmidrule{20-22}\cmidrule{23-25}
    \cmidrule{26-28}\cmidrule{29-31}
W(3,n)  & {1} & {2} & {3}   & {1} & {2} & {3}   & {1} & {2} & {3}   & {1} & {2} & {3}
        & {1} & {2} & {3}   & {1} & {2} & {3}   & {1} & {2} & {3}   & {1} & {2} & {3}
        & {1} & {2} & {3}   & {1} & {2} & {3}                   \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
    \caption{$L(2,1)$-labeling of each vertex in triangular windmill graph (cont.)}\\
\toprule
    & \mc{v(1,i)}   & \mc{v(2,i)}   & \mc{v(3,i)}   & \mc{v(4,i)}
    & \mc{v(5,i)}   & \mc{v(6,i)}   & \mc{v(7,i)}   & \mc{v(8,i)}
    & \mc{v(9,i)}   & \mc{v(10,i)}                      \\
    \cmidrule{2-4}  \cmidrule{5-7}  \cmidrule{8-10} \cmidrule{11-13}
    \cmidrule{14-16}\cmidrule{17-19}\cmidrule{20-22}\cmidrule{23-25}
    \cmidrule{26-28}\cmidrule{29-31}
W(3,n)  & {1} & {2} & {3}   & {1} & {2} & {3}   & {1} & {2} & {3}   & {1} & {2} & {3}
        & {1} & {2} & {3}   & {1} & {2} & {3}   & {1} & {2} & {3}   & {1} & {2} & {3}
        & {1} & {2} & {3}   & {1} & {2} & {3}                   \\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{31}{r}{\textit{continue is on the next page}}
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
W(3,1) & 2 & 4 & 6 \\
W(3,2) & 2 & 4 & 6 & 3 & 5 & 7 \\
W(3,3) & 2 & 5 & 8 & 3 & 6 & 9 & 4 & 7 & 10 \\
W(3,4) & 2 & 6 & 10 & 3 & 7 & 11 & 4 & 8 & 12 & 5 & 9 & 13\\
W(3,5) & 2 & 7 & 12 & 3 & 8 & 13 & 4 & 9 & 14 & 5 & 10 & 15 & 6 & 11 & 16\\
    \addlinespace
W(3,6) & 2 & 8 & 14 & 3 & 9 & 15 & 4 & 10 & 16 & 5 & 11 & 17 & 6 & 12 & 18 & 7 & 13 & 19 \\
W(3,7) & 2 & 9 & 16 & 3 & 10 & 17 & 4 & 11 & 18 & 5 & 12 & 19 & 6 & 13 & 20 & 7 & 14 & 21 & 8 & 15 & 22 \\
W(3,8) & 2 & 10 & 18 & 3 & 11 & 19 & 4 & 12 & 20 & 5 & 13 & 21 & 6 & 14 & 22 & 7 & 15 & 23 & 8 & 16 & 24 & 9 & 17 & 25 \\
W(3,9) & 2 & 11 & 20 & 3 & 12 & 21 & 4 & 13 & 22 & 5 & 14 & 23 & 6 & 15 & 24 & 7 & 16 & 25 & 8 & 17 & 26 & 9 & 18 & 27 & 10 & 19 & 28 \\
W(3,10) & 2 & 12 & 22 & 3 & 13 & 23 & 4 & 14 & 24 & 5 & 15 & 25 & 6 & 16 & 26 & 7 & 17 & 27 & 8 & 18 & 28 & 9 & 19 & 29 & 10 & 20 & 30 & 11 & 21 & 31\\
    \addlinespace
W(3,11) & 2 & 13 & 24 & 3 & 14 & 25 & 4 & 15 & 26 & 5 & 16 & 27 & 6 & 17 & 28 & 7 & 18 & 29 & 8 & 19 & 30 & 9 & 20 & 31 & 10 & 21 & 32 & 11 & 22 & 33\\
W(3,12) & 2 & 14 & 26 & 3 & 15 & 27 & 4 & 16 & 28 & 5 & 17 & 29 & 6 & 18 & 30 & 7 & 19 & 31 & 8 & 20 & 32 & 9 & 21 & 33 & 10 & 22 & 34 & 11 & 23 & 35\\
W(3,13) & 2 & 15 & 28 & 3 & 16 & 29 & 4 & 17 & 30 & 5 & 18 & 31 & 6 & 19 & 32 & 7 & 20 & 33 & 8 & 21 & 34 & 9 & 22 & 35 & 10 & 23 & 36 & 11 & 24 & 37\\
W(3,14) & 2 & 16 & 30 & 3 & 17 & 31 & 4 & 18 & 32 & 5 & 19 & 33 & 6 & 20 & 34 & 7 & 21 & 35 & 8 & 22 & 36 & 9 & 23 & 37 & 10 & 24 & 38 & 11 & 25 & 39\\
W(3,15) & 2 & 17 & 32 & 3 & 18 & 33 & 4 & 19 & 34 & 5 & 20 & 35 & 6 & 21 & 36 & 7 & 22 & 37 & 8 & 23 & 38 & 9 & 24 & 39 & 10 & 25 & 40 & 11 & 26 & 41\\
    \addlinespace
W(3,16) & 2 & 18 & 34 & 3 & 19 & 35 & 4 & 20 & 36 & 5 & 21 & 37 & 6 & 22 & 38 & 7 & 23 & 39 & 8 & 24 & 40 & 9 & 25 & 41 & 10 & 26 & 42 & 11 & 27 & 43\\
W(3,17) & 2 & 19 & 36 & 3 & 20 & 37 & 4 & 21 & 38 & 5 & 22 & 39 & 6 & 23 & 40 & 7 & 24 & 41 & 8 & 25 & 42 & 9 & 26 & 43 & 10 & 27 & 44 & 11 & 28 & 45\\
W(3,18) & 2 & 20 & 38 & 3 & 21 & 39 & 4 & 22 & 40 & 5 & 23 & 41 & 6 & 24 & 42 & 7 & 25 & 43 & 8 & 26 & 44 & 9 & 27 & 45 & 10 & 28 & 46 & 11 & 29 & 47\\
W(3,19) & 2 & 21 & 40 & 3 & 22 & 41 & 4 & 23 & 42 & 5 & 24 & 43 & 6 & 25 & 44 & 7 & 26 & 45 & 8 & 27 & 46 & 9 & 28 & 47 & 10 & 29 & 48 & 11 & 30 & 49\\
W(3,20) & 2 & 22 & 42 & 3 & 23 & 43 & 4 & 24 & 44 & 5 & 25 & 45 & 6 & 26 & 46 & 7 & 27 & 47 & 8 & 28 & 48 & 9 & 29 & 49 & 10 & 30 & 50 & 11 & 31 & 51\\
    \addlinespace
W(3,21) & 2 & 23 & 44 & 3 & 24 & 45 & 4 & 25 & 46 & 5 & 26 & 47 & 6 & 27 & 48 & 7 & 28 & 49 & 8 & 29 & 50 & 9 & 30 & 51 & 10 & 31 & 52 & 11 & 32 & 53\\
W(3,22) & 2 & 24 & 46 & 3 & 25 & 47 & 4 & 26 & 48 & 5 & 27 & 49 & 6 & 28 & 50 & 7 & 29 & 51 & 8 & 30 & 52 & 9 & 31 & 53 & 10 & 32 & 54 & 11 & 33 & 55\\
W(3,23) & 2 & 25 & 48 & 3 & 26 & 49 & 4 & 27 & 50 & 5 & 28 & 51 & 6 & 29 & 52 & 7 & 30 & 53 & 8 & 31 & 54 & 9 & 32 & 55 & 10 & 33 & 56 & 11 & 34 & 57\\
W(3,24) & 2 & 26 & 50 & 3 & 27 & 51 & 4 & 28 & 52 & 5 & 29 & 53 & 6 & 30 & 54 & 7 & 31 & 55 & 8 & 32 & 56 & 9 & 33 & 57 & 10 & 34 & 58 & 11 & 35 & 59 \\
W(3,25) & 2 & 27 & 52 & 3 & 28 & 53 & 4 & 29 & 54 & 5 & 30 & 55 & 6 & 31 & 56 & 7 & 32 & 57 & 8 & 33 & 58 & 9 & 34 & 59 & 10 & 35 & 60 & 11 & 36 & 61\\
    \addlinespace
W(3,26) & 2 & 28 & 54 & 3 & 29 & 55 & 4 & 30 & 56 & 5 & 31 & 57 & 6 & 32 & 58 & 7 & 33 & 59 & 8 & 34 & 60 & 9 & 35 & 61 & 10 & 36 & 62 & 11 & 37 & 63\\
W(3,27) & 2 & 29 & 56 & 3 & 30 & 57 & 4 & 31 & 58 & 5 & 32 & 59 & 6 & 33 & 60 & 7 & 34 & 61 & 8 & 35 & 62 & 9 & 36 & 63 & 10 & 37 & 64 & 11 & 38 & 65\\
W(3,28) & 2 & 30 & 58 & 3 & 31 & 59 & 4 & 32 & 60 & 5 & 33 & 61 & 6 & 34 & 62 & 7 & 35 & 63 & 8 & 36 & 64 & 9 & 37 & 65 & 10 & 38 & 66 & 11 & 39 & 67\\
W(3,29) & 2 & 31 & 60 & 3 & 32 & 61 & 4 & 33 & 62 & 5 & 34 & 63 & 6 & 35 & 64 & 7 & 36 & 65 & 8 & 37 & 66 & 9 & 38 & 67 & 10 & 39 & 68 & 11 & 40 & 69\\
W(3,30) & 2 & 32 & 62 & 3 & 33 & 63 & 4 & 34 & 64 & 5 & 35 & 65 & 6 & 36 & 66 & 7 & 37 & 67 & 8 & 38 & 68 & 9 & 39 & 69 & 10 & 40 & 70 & 11 & 41 & 71\\
    \addlinespace
W(3,31) & 2 & 33 & 64 & 3 & 34 & 65 & 4 & 35 & 66 & 5 & 36 & 67 & 6 & 37 & 68 & 7 & 38 & 69 & 8 & 39 & 70 & 9 & 40 & 71 & 10 & 41 & 72 & 11 & 42 & 73\\
W(3,32) & 2 & 34 & 66 & 3 & 35 & 67 & 4 & 36 & 68 & 5 & 37 & 69 & 6 & 38 & 70 & 7 & 39 & 71 & 8 & 40 & 72 & 9 & 41 & 73 & 10 & 42 & 74 & 11 & 43 & 75\\
W(3,33) & 2 & 35 & 68 & 3 & 36 & 69 & 4 & 37 & 70 & 5 & 38 & 71 & 6 & 39 & 72 & 7 & 40 & 73 & 8 & 41 & 74 & 9 & 42 & 75 & 10 & 43 & 76 & 11 & 44 & 77\\
W(3,34) & 2 & 36 & 70 & 3 & 37 & 71 & 4 & 38 & 72 & 5 & 39 & 73 & 6 & 40 & 74 & 7 & 41 & 75 & 8 & 42 & 76 & 9 & 43 & 77 & 10 & 44 & 78 & 11 & 45 & 79\\
W(3,35) & 2 & 37 & 72 & 3 & 38 & 73 & 4 & 39 & 74 & 5 & 40 & 75 & 6 & 41 & 76 & 7 & 42 & 77 & 8 & 43 & 78 & 9 & 44 & 79 & 10 & 45 & 80 & 11 & 46 & 81\\
    \addlinespace
W(3,36) & 2 & 38 & 74 & 3 & 39 & 75 & 4 & 40 & 76 & 5 & 41 & 77 & 6 & 42 & 78 & 7 & 43 & 79 & 8 & 44 & 80 & 9 & 45 & 81 & 10 & 46 & 82 & 11 & 47 & 83\\
W(3,37) & 2 & 39 & 76 & 3 & 40 & 77 & 4 & 41 & 78 & 5 & 42 & 79 & 6 & 43 & 80 & 7 & 44 & 81 & 8 & 45 & 82 & 9 & 46 & 83 & 10 & 47 & 84 & 11 & 48 & 85\\
W(3,38) & 2 & 40 & 78 & 3 & 41 & 79 & 4 & 42 & 80 & 5 & 43 & 81 & 6 & 44 & 82 & 7 & 45 & 83 & 8 & 46 & 84 & 9 & 47 & 85 & 10 & 48 & 86 & 11 & 49 & 87\\
W(3,39) & 2 & 41 & 80 & 3 & 42 & 81 & 4 & 43 & 82 & 5 & 44 & 83 & 6 & 45 & 84 & 7 & 46 & 85 & 8 & 47 & 86 & 9 & 48 & 87 & 10 & 49 & 88 & 11 & 50 & 89\\
W(3,40) & 2 & 42 & 82 & 3 & 43 & 83 & 4 & 44 & 84 & 5 & 45 & 85 & 6 & 46 & 86 & 7 & 47 & 87 & 8 & 48 & 88 & 9 & 49 & 89 & 10 & 50 & 90 & 11 & 51 & 91\\
    \addlinespace
W(3,41) & 2 & 43 & 84 & 3 & 44 & 85 & 4 & 45 & 86 & 5 & 46 & 87 & 6 & 47 & 88 & 7 & 48 & 89 & 8 & 49 & 90 & 9 & 50 & 91 & 10 & 51 & 92 & 11 & 52 & 93\\
W(3,42) & 2 & 44 & 86 & 3 & 45 & 87 & 4 & 46 & 88 & 5 & 47 & 89 & 6 & 48 & 90 & 7 & 49 & 91 & 8 & 50 & 92 & 9 & 51 & 93 & 10 & 52 & 94 & 11 & 53 & 95\\
W(3,43) & 2 & 45 & 88 & 3 & 46 & 89 & 4 & 47 & 90 & 5 & 48 & 91 & 6 & 49 & 92 & 7 & 50 & 93 & 8 & 51 & 94 & 9 & 52 & 95 & 10 & 53 & 96 & 11 & 54 & 97\\
W(3,44) & 2 & 46 & 90 & 3 & 47 & 91 & 4 & 48 & 92 & 5 & 49 & 93 & 6 & 50 & 94 & 7 & 51 & 95 & 8 & 52 & 96 & 9 & 53 & 97 & 10 & 54 & 98 & 11 & 55 & 99\\
W(3,45) & 2 & 47 & 92 & 3 & 48 & 93 & 4 & 49 & 94 & 5 & 50 & 95 & 6 & 51 & 96 & 7 & 52 & 97 & 8 & 53 & 98 & 9 & 54 & 99 & 10 & 55 & 100 & 11 & 56 & 101\\
    \addlinespace
W(3,46) & 2 & 48 & 94 & 3 & 49 & 95 & 4 & 50 & 96 & 5 & 51 & 97 & 6 & 52 & 98 & 7 & 53 & 99 & 8 & 54 & 100 & 9 & 55 & 101 & 10 & 56 & 102 & 11 & 57 & 103\\
W(3,47) & 2 & 49 & 96 & 3 & 50 & 97 & 4 & 51 & 98 & 5 & 52 & 99 & 6 & 53 & 100 & 7 & 54 & 101 & 8 & 55 & 102 & 9 & 56 & 103 & 10 & 57 & 104 & 11 & 58 & 105\\
W(3,48) & 2 & 50 & 98 & 3 & 51 & 99 & 4 & 52 & 100 & 5 & 53 & 101 & 6 & 54 & 102 & 7 & 55 & 103 & 8 & 56 & 104 & 9 & 57 & 105 & 10 & 58 & 106 & 11 & 59 & 107\\
W(3,49) & 2 & 51 & 100 & 3 & 52 & 101 & 4 & 53 & 102 & 5 & 54 & 103 & 6 & 55 & 104 & 7 & 56 & 105 & 8 & 57 & 106 & 9 & 58 & 107 & 10 & 59 & 108 & 11 & 60 & 109\\
W(3,50) & 2 & 52 & 102 & 3 & 53 & 103 & 4 & 54 & 104 & 5 & 55 & 105 & 6 & 56 & 106 & 7 & 57 & 107 & 8 & 58 & 108 & 9 & 59 & 109 & 10 & 60 & 110 & 11 & 61 & 111\\
    \addlinespace
W(3,51) & 2 & 53 & 104 & 3 & 54 & 105 & 4 & 55 & 106 & 5 & 56 & 107 & 6 & 57 & 108 & 7 & 58 & 109 & 8 & 59 & 110 & 9 & 60 & 111 & 10 & 61 & 112 & 11 & 62 & 113\\
W(3,52) & 2 & 54 & 106 & 3 & 55 & 107 & 4 & 56 & 108 & 5 & 57 & 109 & 6 & 58 & 110 & 7 & 59 & 111 & 8 & 60 & 112 & 9 & 61 & 113 & 10 & 62 & 114 & 11 & 63 & 115\\
W(3,53) & 2 & 55 & 108 & 3 & 56 & 109 & 4 & 57 & 110 & 5 & 58 & 111 & 6 & 59 & 112 & 7 & 60 & 113 & 8 & 61 & 114 & 9 & 62 & 115 & 10 & 63 & 116 & 11 & 64 & 117\\
W(3,54) & 2 & 56 & 110 & 3 & 57 & 111 & 4 & 58 & 112 & 5 & 59 & 113 & 6 & 60 & 114 & 7 & 61 & 115 & 8 & 62 & 116 & 9 & 63 & 117 & 10 & 64 & 118 & 11 & 65 & 119\\
W(3,55) & 2 & 57 & 112 & 3 & 58 & 113 & 4 & 59 & 114 & 5 & 60 & 115 & 6 & 61 & 116 & 7 & 62 & 117 & 8 & 63 & 118 & 9 & 64 & 119 & 10 & 65 & 120 & 11 & 66 & 121\\
    \addlinespace
W(3,56) & 2 & 58 & 114 & 3 & 59 & 115 & 4 & 60 & 116 & 5 & 61 & 117 & 6 & 62 & 118 & 7 & 63 & 119 & 8 & 64 & 120 & 9 & 65 & 121 & 10 & 66 & 122 & 11 & 67 & 123\\
W(3,57) & 2 & 59 & 116 & 3 & 60 & 117 & 4 & 61 & 118 & 5 & 62 & 119 & 6 & 63 & 120 & 7 & 64 & 121 & 8 & 65 & 122 & 9 & 66 & 123 & 10 & 67 & 124 & 11 & 68 & 125\\
W(3,58) & 2 & 60 & 118 & 3 & 61 & 119 & 4 & 62 & 120 & 5 & 63 & 121 & 6 & 64 & 122 & 7 & 65 & 123 & 8 & 66 & 124 & 9 & 67 & 125 & 10 & 68 & 126 & 11 & 69 & 127\\
W(3,59) & 2 & 61 & 120 & 3 & 62 & 121 & 4 & 63 & 122 & 5 & 64 & 123 & 6 & 65 & 124 & 7 & 66 & 125 & 8 & 67 & 126 & 9 & 68 & 127 & 10 & 69 & 128 & 11 & 70 & 129\\
W(3,60) & 2 & 62 & 122 & 3 & 63 & 123 & 4 & 64 & 24 & 5 & 65 & 125 & 6 & 66 & 126 & 7 & 67 & 127 & 8 & 68 & 128 & 9 & 69 & 128 & 10 & 70 & 130 & 11 & 71 & 131\\
    \end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Nice touch to insert `\addlinespace` after every 5th row!

Answer (score 3):

If your document has standard margins (ca 1", or 2.5cm) and if you're willing to use a `\tiny` font size, along with no vertical lines, very few horizontal lines, and very little whitespace between the columns, it is just, *but only just*, possible to fit the entire table on one page, by turning it 90 degrees, i.e., by using landscape mode. No need to use a `longtable`, actually. To improve legibility ever so slightly, I would suggest that you not center-set the contents of the numeric columns but, instead, align the numbers on the (implicit) decimal markers; this may be done by loading the `siunitx` package and using its `S` column type.

Do ask yourself, please, what a reader is likely to take away from staring at a table that comprises 30 [!] data columns and 60 [!!] data rows. If you suspect that the answer might be "nothing at all," do your readers (and yourself!) a big favor by showing far fewer numbers -- but hopefully just the most relevant ones.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page dimensions
\usepackage{caption,rotating,booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\captionsetup{font=scriptsize}
\tiny
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{30}{S[table-format=3.0]}}
\toprule
W(3,n) & {v(1,1)} & {v(1,2)} & {v(1,3)} & {v(2,1)}  & {v(2,2)} & {v(2,3)} & {v(3,1)} & {v(3,2)} & {v(3,3)} & {v(4,1)} & {v(4,2)} & {v(4,3)} & {v(5,1)} & {v(5,2)} & {v(5,3)} & {v(6,1)}  & {v(6,2)} & {v(6,3)} & {v(7,1)} & {v(7,2)} & {v(7,3)} & {v(8,1)}  & {v(8,2)} & {v(8,3)} & {v(9,1)} & {v(9,2)} & {v(9,3)} & {v(10,1)} & {v(10,2)}& {v(10,3)} \\
\midrule
W(3,1) & 2 & 4 & 6 \\
W(3,2) & 2 & 4 & 6 & 3 & 5 & 7 \\
W(3,3) & 2 & 5 & 8 & 3 & 6 & 9 & 4 & 7 & 10 \\
W(3,4) & 2 & 6 & 10 & 3 & 7 & 11 & 4 & 8 & 12 & 5 & 9 & 13\\
W(3,5) & 2 & 7 & 12 & 3 & 8 & 13 & 4 & 9 & 14 & 5 & 10 & 15 & 6 & 11 & 16\\
W(3,6) & 2 & 8 & 14 & 3 & 9 & 15 & 4 & 10 & 16 & 5 & 11 & 17 & 6 & 12 & 18 & 7 & 13 & 19 \\
W(3,7) & 2 & 9 & 16 & 3 & 10 & 17 & 4 & 11 & 18 & 5 & 12 & 19 & 6 & 13 & 20 & 7 & 14 & 21 & 8 & 15 & 22 \\
W(3,8) & 2 & 10 & 18 & 3 & 11 & 19 & 4 & 12 & 20 & 5 & 13 & 21 & 6 & 14 & 22 & 7 & 15 & 23 & 8 & 16 & 24 & 9 & 17 & 25 \\
W(3,9) & 2 & 11 & 20 & 3 & 12 & 21 & 4 & 13 & 22 & 5 & 14 & 23 & 6 & 15 & 24 & 7 & 16 & 25 & 8 & 17 & 26 & 9 & 18 & 27 & 10 & 19 & 28 \\
W(3,10) & 2 & 12 & 22 & 3 & 13 & 23 & 4 & 14 & 24 & 5 & 15 & 25 & 6 & 16 & 26 & 7 & 17 & 27 & 8 & 18 & 28 & 9 & 19 & 29 & 10 & 20 & 30 & 11 & 21 & 31\\
W(3,11) & 2 & 13 & 24 & 3 & 14 & 25 & 4 & 15 & 26 & 5 & 16 & 27 & 6 & 17 & 28 & 7 & 18 & 29 & 8 & 19 & 30 & 9 & 20 & 31 & 10 & 21 & 32 & 11 & 22 & 33\\
W(3,12) & 2 & 14 & 26 & 3 & 15 & 27 & 4 & 16 & 28 & 5 & 17 & 29 & 6 & 18 & 30 & 7 & 19 & 31 & 8 & 20 & 32 & 9 & 21 & 33 & 10 & 22 & 34 & 11 & 23 & 35\\
W(3,13) & 2 & 15 & 28 & 3 & 16 & 29 & 4 & 17 & 30 & 5 & 18 & 31 & 6 & 19 & 32 & 7 & 20 & 33 & 8 & 21 & 34 & 9 & 22 & 35 & 10 & 23 & 36 & 11 & 24 & 37\\
W(3,14) & 2 & 16 & 30 & 3 & 17 & 31 & 4 & 18 & 32 & 5 & 19 & 33 & 6 & 20 & 34 & 7 & 21 & 35 & 8 & 22 & 36 & 9 & 23 & 37 & 10 & 24 & 38 & 11 & 25 & 39\\
W(3,15) & 2 & 17 & 32 & 3 & 18 & 33 & 4 & 19 & 34 & 5 & 20 & 35 & 6 & 21 & 36 & 7 & 22 & 37 & 8 & 23 & 38 & 9 & 24 & 39 & 10 & 25 & 40 & 11 & 26 & 41\\
W(3,16) & 2 & 18 & 34 & 3 & 19 & 35 & 4 & 20 & 36 & 5 & 21 & 37 & 6 & 22 & 38 & 7 & 23 & 39 & 8 & 24 & 40 & 9 & 25 & 41 & 10 & 26 & 42 & 11 & 27 & 43\\
W(3,17) & 2 & 19 & 36 & 3 & 20 & 37 & 4 & 21 & 38 & 5 & 22 & 39 & 6 & 23 & 40 & 7 & 24 & 41 & 8 & 25 & 42 & 9 & 26 & 43 & 10 & 27 & 44 & 11 & 28 & 45\\
W(3,18) & 2 & 20 & 38 & 3 & 21 & 39 & 4 & 22 & 40 & 5 & 23 & 41 & 6 & 24 & 42 & 7 & 25 & 43 & 8 & 26 & 44 & 9 & 27 & 45 & 10 & 28 & 46 & 11 & 29 & 47\\
W(3,19) & 2 & 21 & 40 & 3 & 22 & 41 & 4 & 23 & 42 & 5 & 24 & 43 & 6 & 25 & 44 & 7 & 26 & 45 & 8 & 27 & 46 & 9 & 28 & 47 & 10 & 29 & 48 & 11 & 30 & 49\\
W(3,20) & 2 & 22 & 42 & 3 & 23 & 43 & 4 & 24 & 44 & 5 & 25 & 45 & 6 & 26 & 46 & 7 & 27 & 47 & 8 & 28 & 48 & 9 & 29 & 49 & 10 & 30 & 50 & 11 & 31 & 51\\
W(3,21) & 2 & 23 & 44 & 3 & 24 & 45 & 4 & 25 & 46 & 5 & 26 & 47 & 6 & 27 & 48 & 7 & 28 & 49 & 8 & 29 & 50 & 9 & 30 & 51 & 10 & 31 & 52 & 11 & 32 & 53\\
W(3,22) & 2 & 24 & 46 & 3 & 25 & 47 & 4 & 26 & 48 & 5 & 27 & 49 & 6 & 28 & 50 & 7 & 29 & 51 & 8 & 30 & 52 & 9 & 31 & 53 & 10 & 32 & 54 & 11 & 33 & 55\\
W(3,23) & 2 & 25 & 48 & 3 & 26 & 49 & 4 & 27 & 50 & 5 & 28 & 51 & 6 & 29 & 52 & 7 & 30 & 53 & 8 & 31 & 54 & 9 & 32 & 55 & 10 & 33 & 56 & 11 & 34 & 57\\
W(3,24) & 2 & 26 & 50 & 3 & 27 & 51 & 4 & 28 & 52 & 5 & 29 & 53 & 6 & 30 & 54 & 7 & 31 & 55 & 8 & 32 & 56 & 9 & 33 & 57 & 10 & 34 & 58 & 11 & 35 & 59 \\
W(3,25) & 2 & 27 & 52 & 3 & 28 & 53 & 4 & 29 & 54 & 5 & 30 & 55 & 6 & 31 & 56 & 7 & 32 & 57 & 8 & 33 & 58 & 9 & 34 & 59 & 10 & 35 & 60 & 11 & 36 & 61\\
W(3,26) & 2 & 28 & 54 & 3 & 29 & 55 & 4 & 30 & 56 & 5 & 31 & 57 & 6 & 32 & 58 & 7 & 33 & 59 & 8 & 34 & 60 & 9 & 35 & 61 & 10 & 36 & 62 & 11 & 37 & 63\\
W(3,27) & 2 & 29 & 56 & 3 & 30 & 57 & 4 & 31 & 58 & 5 & 32 & 59 & 6 & 33 & 60 & 7 & 34 & 61 & 8 & 35 & 62 & 9 & 36 & 63 & 10 & 37 & 64 & 11 & 38 & 65\\
W(3,28) & 2 & 30 & 58 & 3 & 31 & 59 & 4 & 32 & 60 & 5 & 33 & 61 & 6 & 34 & 62 & 7 & 35 & 63 & 8 & 36 & 64 & 9 & 37 & 65 & 10 & 38 & 66 & 11 & 39 & 67\\
W(3,29) & 2 & 31 & 60 & 3 & 32 & 61 & 4 & 33 & 62 & 5 & 34 & 63 & 6 & 35 & 64 & 7 & 36 & 65 & 8 & 37 & 66 & 9 & 38 & 67 & 10 & 39 & 68 & 11 & 40 & 69\\
W(3,30) & 2 & 32 & 62 & 3 & 33 & 63 & 4 & 34 & 64 & 5 & 35 & 65 & 6 & 36 & 66 & 7 & 37 & 67 & 8 & 38 & 68 & 9 & 39 & 69 & 10 & 40 & 70 & 11 & 41 & 71\\
W(3,31) & 2 & 33 & 64 & 3 & 34 & 65 & 4 & 35 & 66 & 5 & 36 & 67 & 6 & 37 & 68 & 7 & 38 & 69 & 8 & 39 & 70 & 9 & 40 & 71 & 10 & 41 & 72 & 11 & 42 & 73\\
W(3,32) & 2 & 34 & 66 & 3 & 35 & 67 & 4 & 36 & 68 & 5 & 37 & 69 & 6 & 38 & 70 & 7 & 39 & 71 & 8 & 40 & 72 & 9 & 41 & 73 & 10 & 42 & 74 & 11 & 43 & 75\\
W(3,33) & 2 & 35 & 68 & 3 & 36 & 69 & 4 & 37 & 70 & 5 & 38 & 71 & 6 & 39 & 72 & 7 & 40 & 73 & 8 & 41 & 74 & 9 & 42 & 75 & 10 & 43 & 76 & 11 & 44 & 77\\
W(3,34) & 2 & 36 & 70 & 3 & 37 & 71 & 4 & 38 & 72 & 5 & 39 & 73 & 6 & 40 & 74 & 7 & 41 & 75 & 8 & 42 & 76 & 9 & 43 & 77 & 10 & 44 & 78 & 11 & 45 & 79\\
W(3,35) & 2 & 37 & 72 & 3 & 38 & 73 & 4 & 39 & 74 & 5 & 40 & 75 & 6 & 41 & 76 & 7 & 42 & 77 & 8 & 43 & 78 & 9 & 44 & 79 & 10 & 45 & 80 & 11 & 46 & 81\\
W(3,36) & 2 & 38 & 74 & 3 & 39 & 75 & 4 & 40 & 76 & 5 & 41 & 77 & 6 & 42 & 78 & 7 & 43 & 79 & 8 & 44 & 80 & 9 & 45 & 81 & 10 & 46 & 82 & 11 & 47 & 83\\
W(3,37) & 2 & 39 & 76 & 3 & 40 & 77 & 4 & 41 & 78 & 5 & 42 & 79 & 6 & 43 & 80 & 7 & 44 & 81 & 8 & 45 & 82 & 9 & 46 & 83 & 10 & 47 & 84 & 11 & 48 & 85\\
W(3,38) & 2 & 40 & 78 & 3 & 41 & 79 & 4 & 42 & 80 & 5 & 43 & 81 & 6 & 44 & 82 & 7 & 45 & 83 & 8 & 46 & 84 & 9 & 47 & 85 & 10 & 48 & 86 & 11 & 49 & 87\\
W(3,39) & 2 & 41 & 80 & 3 & 42 & 81 & 4 & 43 & 82 & 5 & 44 & 83 & 6 & 45 & 84 & 7 & 46 & 85 & 8 & 47 & 86 & 9 & 48 & 87 & 10 & 49 & 88 & 11 & 50 & 89\\
W(3,40) & 2 & 42 & 82 & 3 & 43 & 83 & 4 & 44 & 84 & 5 & 45 & 85 & 6 & 46 & 86 & 7 & 47 & 87 & 8 & 48 & 88 & 9 & 49 & 89 & 10 & 50 & 90 & 11 & 51 & 91\\
W(3,41) & 2 & 43 & 84 & 3 & 44 & 85 & 4 & 45 & 86 & 5 & 46 & 87 & 6 & 47 & 88 & 7 & 48 & 89 & 8 & 49 & 90 & 9 & 50 & 91 & 10 & 51 & 92 & 11 & 52 & 93\\
W(3,42) & 2 & 44 & 86 & 3 & 45 & 87 & 4 & 46 & 88 & 5 & 47 & 89 & 6 & 48 & 90 & 7 & 49 & 91 & 8 & 50 & 92 & 9 & 51 & 93 & 10 & 52 & 94 & 11 & 53 & 95\\
W(3,43) & 2 & 45 & 88 & 3 & 46 & 89 & 4 & 47 & 90 & 5 & 48 & 91 & 6 & 49 & 92 & 7 & 50 & 93 & 8 & 51 & 94 & 9 & 52 & 95 & 10 & 53 & 96 & 11 & 54 & 97\\
W(3,44) & 2 & 46 & 90 & 3 & 47 & 91 & 4 & 48 & 92 & 5 & 49 & 93 & 6 & 50 & 94 & 7 & 51 & 95 & 8 & 52 & 96 & 9 & 53 & 97 & 10 & 54 & 98 & 11 & 55 & 99\\
W(3,45) & 2 & 47 & 92 & 3 & 48 & 93 & 4 & 49 & 94 & 5 & 50 & 95 & 6 & 51 & 96 & 7 & 52 & 97 & 8 & 53 & 98 & 9 & 54 & 99 & 10 & 55 & 100 & 11 & 56 & 101\\
W(3,46) & 2 & 48 & 94 & 3 & 49 & 95 & 4 & 50 & 96 & 5 & 51 & 97 & 6 & 52 & 98 & 7 & 53 & 99 & 8 & 54 & 100 & 9 & 55 & 101 & 10 & 56 & 102 & 11 & 57 & 103\\
W(3,47) & 2 & 49 & 96 & 3 & 50 & 97 & 4 & 51 & 98 & 5 & 52 & 99 & 6 & 53 & 100 & 7 & 54 & 101 & 8 & 55 & 102 & 9 & 56 & 103 & 10 & 57 & 104 & 11 & 58 & 105\\
W(3,48) & 2 & 50 & 98 & 3 & 51 & 99 & 4 & 52 & 100 & 5 & 53 & 101 & 6 & 54 & 102 & 7 & 55 & 103 & 8 & 56 & 104 & 9 & 57 & 105 & 10 & 58 & 106 & 11 & 59 & 107\\
W(3,49) & 2 & 51 & 100 & 3 & 52 & 101 & 4 & 53 & 102 & 5 & 54 & 103 & 6 & 55 & 104 & 7 & 56 & 105 & 8 & 57 & 106 & 9 & 58 & 107 & 10 & 59 & 108 & 11 & 60 & 109\\
W(3,50) & 2 & 52 & 102 & 3 & 53 & 103 & 4 & 54 & 104 & 5 & 55 & 105 & 6 & 56 & 106 & 7 & 57 & 107 & 8 & 58 & 108 & 9 & 59 & 109 & 10 & 60 & 110 & 11 & 61 & 111\\
W(3,51) & 2 & 53 & 104 & 3 & 54 & 105 & 4 & 55 & 106 & 5 & 56 & 107 & 6 & 57 & 108 & 7 & 58 & 109 & 8 & 59 & 110 & 9 & 60 & 111 & 10 & 61 & 112 & 11 & 62 & 113\\
W(3,52) & 2 & 54 & 106 & 3 & 55 & 107 & 4 & 56 & 108 & 5 & 57 & 109 & 6 & 58 & 110 & 7 & 59 & 111 & 8 & 60 & 112 & 9 & 61 & 113 & 10 & 62 & 114 & 11 & 63 & 115\\
W(3,53) & 2 & 55 & 108 & 3 & 56 & 109 & 4 & 57 & 110 & 5 & 58 & 111 & 6 & 59 & 112 & 7 & 60 & 113 & 8 & 61 & 114 & 9 & 62 & 115 & 10 & 63 & 116 & 11 & 64 & 117\\
W(3,54) & 2 & 56 & 110 & 3 & 57 & 111 & 4 & 58 & 112 & 5 & 59 & 113 & 6 & 60 & 114 & 7 & 61 & 115 & 8 & 62 & 116 & 9 & 63 & 117 & 10 & 64 & 118 & 11 & 65 & 119\\
W(3,55) & 2 & 57 & 112 & 3 & 58 & 113 & 4 & 59 & 114 & 5 & 60 & 115 & 6 & 61 & 116 & 7 & 62 & 117 & 8 & 63 & 118 & 9 & 64 & 119 & 10 & 65 & 120 & 11 & 66 & 121\\
W(3,56) & 2 & 58 & 114 & 3 & 59 & 115 & 4 & 60 & 116 & 5 & 61 & 117 & 6 & 62 & 118 & 7 & 63 & 119 & 8 & 64 & 120 & 9 & 65 & 121 & 10 & 66 & 122 & 11 & 67 & 123\\
W(3,57) & 2 & 59 & 116 & 3 & 60 & 117 & 4 & 61 & 118 & 5 & 62 & 119 & 6 & 63 & 120 & 7 & 64 & 121 & 8 & 65 & 122 & 9 & 66 & 123 & 10 & 67 & 124 & 11 & 68 & 125\\
W(3,58) & 2 & 60 & 118 & 3 & 61 & 119 & 4 & 62 & 120 & 5 & 63 & 121 & 6 & 64 & 122 & 7 & 65 & 123 & 8 & 66 & 124 & 9 & 67 & 125 & 10 & 68 & 126 & 11 & 69 & 127\\
W(3,59) & 2 & 61 & 120 & 3 & 62 & 121 & 4 & 63 & 122 & 5 & 64 & 123 & 6 & 65 & 124 & 7 & 66 & 125 & 8 & 67 & 126 & 9 & 68 & 127 & 10 & 69 & 128 & 11 & 70 & 129\\
W(3,60) & 2 & 62 & 122 & 3 & 63 & 123 & 4 & 64 & 24 & 5 & 65 & 125 & 6 & 66 & 126 & 7 & 67 & 127 & 8 & 68 & 128 & 9 & 69 & 128 & 10 & 70 & 130 & 11 & 71 & 131\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*} 
\caption{$L(2,1)$-labeling of each vertex in triangular windmill graph}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can obtain some space if you rotate column headers :-). maybe this be sufficient to use `\scriptsize` font size

Comment: @Zarko - Thanks. The table shown above barely fits in the textblock, vertically as well has horizontally. If one were to rotate the header cells and switch to `\scriptsize`, one would also have to use a `longtable` environment and let the table span two pages. Feel free to post an answer that implements these ideas. :-) Of course, one would still be stuck with looking at a 1800-cell table...

Answer (score 3):

I propose this layout, with `\footnotesize` and `landscape` orientation. I load  `ltablex` which combines (and loads) `longtable` and `tabularx`, so that  tabularx environments can break across lines. I added some coloured columns, as they seem to be grouped by three, to improve readability. Last, I placed the caption where it should be – at the beginning of the table, and repeated at the beginning of each new page:

```
\documentclass[12pt, svgnames, table]{report}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx, ltablex, makecell, caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\rotbox}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{\rlap{\rotatebox[origin =cb]{45}{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\colrotbox}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{\rlap{\rotatebox[origin =ct]{45}{\fboxsep =0.5pt\colorbox{WhiteSmoke}{#1}}}}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\keepXColumns{
\begin{landscape}
\noindent%
\footnotesize%
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}%
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\captionsetup{font = bf, labelsep = period, justification = centerlast}
\arrayrulecolor{red}%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|*{10}{ >{\columncolor{WhiteSmoke}}c| p{5.5mm}|>{\arraybackslash}p{5.5mm}|}}
%%
\caption{\boldmath$L(2,1)$-labeling of each vertex in triangular windmill graph}\\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\thead[lb]{W(3,n)}} & \colrotbox{v(1,1)} & \rotbox{v(1,2)} & \rotbox{v(1,3)} & \colrotbox{v(2,1)} & \rotbox{v(2,2)} & \rotbox{v(2,3)} & \colrotbox{v(3,1)} & \rotbox{v(3,2)} & \rotbox{v(3,3)} & \colrotbox{v(4,1)} & \rotbox{v(4,2)} & \rotbox{v(4,3)} & \colrotbox{v(5,1)} & \rotbox{v(5,2)} & \rotbox{v(5,3)} & \colrotbox{v(6,1)} & \rotbox{v(6,2)} & \rotbox{v(6,3)} & \colrotbox{v(7,1)} & \rotbox{v(7,2)} & \rotbox{v(7,3)} & \colrotbox{v(8,1)} & \rotbox{v(8,2)} & \rotbox{v(8,3)} & \colrotbox{v(9,1)} & \rotbox{v(9,2)} & \rotbox{v(9,3)} & \colrotbox{v(10,1)} & \rotbox{v(10,2)} & \rotbox{v(10,3)}
 \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{31}{c}{\bfseries\boldmath \tablename~\thetable. $L(2,1)$-labeling of each vertex in triangular windmill graph~\textmd{(continued)}}\medskip \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\thead[lb]{W(3,n)}} & \colrotbox{v(1,1)} & \rotbox{v(1,2)} & \rotbox{v(1,3)} & \colrotbox{v(2,1)} & \rotbox{v(2,2)} & \rotbox{v(2,3)} & \colrotbox{v(3,1)} & \rotbox{v(3,2)} & \rotbox{v(3,3)} & \colrotbox{v(4,1)} & \rotbox{v(4,2)} & \rotbox{v(4,3)} & \colrotbox{v(5,1)} & \rotbox{v(5,2)} & \rotbox{v(5,3)} & \colrotbox{v(6,1)} & \rotbox{v(6,2)} & \rotbox{v(6,3)} & \colrotbox{v(7,1)} & \rotbox{v(7,2)} & \rotbox{v(7,3)} & \colrotbox{v(8,1)} & \rotbox{v(8,2)} & \rotbox{v(8,3)} & \colrotbox{v(9,1)} & \rotbox{v(9,2)} & \rotbox{v(9,3)} & \colrotbox{v(10,1)} & \rotbox{v(10,2)} & \rotbox{v(10,3)}
 \\
\hline
\endhead
\noalign{\smallskip}
\multicolumn{31}{r}{\scriptsize (to be continued)}
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
W(3,1) & 2 & 4 & 6 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
W(3,2) & 2 & 4 & 6 & 3 & 5 & 7 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
W(3,3) & 2 & 5 & 8 & 3 & 6 & 9 & 4 & 7 & 10 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
W(3,4) & 2 & 6 & 10 & 3 & 7 & 11 & 4 & 8 & 12 & 5 & 9 & 13 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
W(3,5) & 2 & 7 & 12 & 3 & 8 & 13 & 4 & 9 & 14 & 5 & 10 & 15 & 6 & 11 & 16 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
W(3,6) & 2 & 8 & 14 & 3 & 9 & 15 & 4 & 10 & 16 & 5 & 11 & 17 & 6 & 12 & 18 & 7 & 13 & 19 & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
W(3,7) & 2 & 9 & 16 & 3 & 10 & 17 & 4 & 11 & 18 & 5 & 12 & 19 & 6 & 13 & 20 & 7 & 14 & 21 & 8 & 15 & 22 & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
W(3,8) & 2 & 10 & 18 & 3 & 11 & 19 & 4 & 12 & 20 & 5 & 13 & 21 & 6 & 14 & 22 & 7 & 15 & 23 & 8 & 16 & 24 & 9 & 17 & 25 & & & & & &\\
\hline
W(3,9) & 2 & 11 & 20 & 3 & 12 & 21 & 4 & 13 & 22 & 5 & 14 & 23 & 6 & 15 & 24 & 7 & 16 & 25 & 8 & 17 & 26 & 9 & 18 & 27 & 10 & 19 & 28 & & &\\
\hline
W(3,10) & 2 & 12 & 22 & 3 & 13 & 23 & 4 & 14 & 24 & 5 & 15 & 25 & 6 & 16 & 26 & 7 & 17 & 27 & 8 & 18 & 28 & 9 & 19 & 29 & 10 & 20 & 30 & 11 & 21 & 31\\
\hline
W(3,11) & 2 & 13 & 24 & 3 & 14 & 25 & 4 & 15 & 26 & 5 & 16 & 27 & 6 & 17 & 28 & 7 & 18 & 29 & 8 & 19 & 30 & 9 & 20 & 31 & 10 & 21 & 32 & 11 & 22 & 33\\
\hline
W(3,12) & 2 & 14 & 26 & 3 & 15 & 27 & 4 & 16 & 28 & 5 & 17 & 29 & 6 & 18 & 30 & 7 & 19 & 31 & 8 & 20 & 32 & 9 & 21 & 33 & 10 & 22 & 34 & 11 & 23 & 35\\
\hline
W(3,13) & 2 & 15 & 28 & 3 & 16 & 29 & 4 & 17 & 30 & 5 & 18 & 31 & 6 & 19 & 32 & 7 & 20 & 33 & 8 & 21 & 34 & 9 & 22 & 35 & 10 & 23 & 36 & 11 & 24 & 37\\
\hline
W(3,14) & 2 & 16 & 30 & 3 & 17 & 31 & 4 & 18 & 32 & 5 & 19 & 33 & 6 & 20 & 34 & 7 & 21 & 35 & 8 & 22 & 36 & 9 & 23 & 37 & 10 & 24 & 38 & 11 & 25 & 39\\
\hline
W(3,15) & 2 & 17 & 32 & 3 & 18 & 33 & 4 & 19 & 34 & 5 & 20 & 35 & 6 & 21 & 36 & 7 & 22 & 37 & 8 & 23 & 38 & 9 & 24 & 39 & 10 & 25 & 40 & 11 & 26 & 41\\
\hline
W(3,16) & 2 & 18 & 34 & 3 & 19 & 35 & 4 & 20 & 36 & 5 & 21 & 37 & 6 & 22 & 38 & 7 & 23 & 39 & 8 & 24 & 40 & 9 & 25 & 41 & 10 & 26 & 42 & 11 & 27 & 43\\
\hline
W(3,17) & 2 & 19 & 36 & 3 & 20 & 37 & 4 & 21 & 38 & 5 & 22 & 39 & 6 & 23 & 40 & 7 & 24 & 41 & 8 & 25 & 42 & 9 & 26 & 43 & 10 & 27 & 44 & 11 & 28 & 45\\
\hline
W(3,18) & 2 & 20 & 38 & 3 & 21 & 39 & 4 & 22 & 40 & 5 & 23 & 41 & 6 & 24 & 42 & 7 & 25 & 43 & 8 & 26 & 44 & 9 & 27 & 45 & 10 & 28 & 46 & 11 & 29 & 47\\
\hline
W(3,19) & 2 & 21 & 40 & 3 & 22 & 41 & 4 & 23 & 42 & 5 & 24 & 43 & 6 & 25 & 44 & 7 & 26 & 45 & 8 & 27 & 46 & 9 & 28 & 47 & 10 & 29 & 48 & 11 & 30 & 49\\
\hline
W(3,20) & 2 & 22 & 42 & 3 & 23 & 43 & 4 & 24 & 44 & 5 & 25 & 45 & 6 & 26 & 46 & 7 & 27 & 47 & 8 & 28 & 48 & 9 & 29 & 49 & 10 & 30 & 50 & 11 & 31 & 51\\
\hline
W(3,21) & 2 & 23 & 44 & 3 & 24 & 45 & 4 & 25 & 46 & 5 & 26 & 47 & 6 & 27 & 48 & 7 & 28 & 49 & 8 & 29 & 50 & 9 & 30 & 51 & 10 & 31 & 52 & 11 & 32 & 53\\
\hline
W(3,22) & 2 & 24 & 46 & 3 & 25 & 47 & 4 & 26 & 48 & 5 & 27 & 49 & 6 & 28 & 50 & 7 & 29 & 51 & 8 & 30 & 52 & 9 & 31 & 53 & 10 & 32 & 54 & 11 & 33 & 55\\
\hline
W(3,23) & 2 & 25 & 48 & 3 & 26 & 49 & 4 & 27 & 50 & 5 & 28 & 51 & 6 & 29 & 52 & 7 & 30 & 53 & 8 & 31 & 54 & 9 & 32 & 55 & 10 & 33 & 56 & 11 & 34 & 57\\
\hline
W(3,24) & 2 & 26 & 50 & 3 & 27 & 51 & 4 & 28 & 52 & 5 & 29 & 53 & 6 & 30 & 54 & 7 & 31 & 55 & 8 & 32 & 56 & 9 & 33 & 57 & 10 & 34 & 58 & 11 & 35 & 59 \\
\hline
W(3,25) & 2 & 27 & 52 & 3 & 28 & 53 & 4 & 29 & 54 & 5 & 30 & 55 & 6 & 31 & 56 & 7 & 32 & 57 & 8 & 33 & 58 & 9 & 34 & 59 & 10 & 35 & 60 & 11 & 36 & 61\\
\hline
W(3,26) & 2 & 28 & 54 & 3 & 29 & 55 & 4 & 30 & 56 & 5 & 31 & 57 & 6 & 32 & 58 & 7 & 33 & 59 & 8 & 34 & 60 & 9 & 35 & 61 & 10 & 36 & 62 & 11 & 37 & 63\\
\hline
W(3,27) & 2 & 29 & 56 & 3 & 30 & 57 & 4 & 31 & 58 & 5 & 32 & 59 & 6 & 33 & 60 & 7 & 34 & 61 & 8 & 35 & 62 & 9 & 36 & 63 & 10 & 37 & 64 & 11 & 38 & 65\\
\hline
W(3,28) & 2 & 30 & 58 & 3 & 31 & 59 & 4 & 32 & 60 & 5 & 33 & 61 & 6 & 34 & 62 & 7 & 35 & 63 & 8 & 36 & 64 & 9 & 37 & 65 & 10 & 38 & 66 & 11 & 39 & 67\\
\hline
W(3,29) & 2 & 31 & 60 & 3 & 32 & 61 & 4 & 33 & 62 & 5 & 34 & 63 & 6 & 35 & 64 & 7 & 36 & 65 & 8 & 37 & 66 & 9 & 38 & 67 & 10 & 39 & 68 & 11 & 40 & 69\\
\hline
W(3,30) & 2 & 32 & 62 & 3 & 33 & 63 & 4 & 34 & 64 & 5 & 35 & 65 & 6 & 36 & 66 & 7 & 37 & 67 & 8 & 38 & 68 & 9 & 39 & 69 & 10 & 40 & 70 & 11 & 41 & 71\\
\hline
W(3,31) & 2 & 33 & 64 & 3 & 34 & 65 & 4 & 35 & 66 & 5 & 36 & 67 & 6 & 37 & 68 & 7 & 38 & 69 & 8 & 39 & 70 & 9 & 40 & 71 & 10 & 41 & 72 & 11 & 42 & 73\\
\hline
W(3,32) & 2 & 34 & 66 & 3 & 35 & 67 & 4 & 36 & 68 & 5 & 37 & 69 & 6 & 38 & 70 & 7 & 39 & 71 & 8 & 40 & 72 & 9 & 41 & 73 & 10 & 42 & 74 & 11 & 43 & 75\\
\hline
W(3,33) & 2 & 35 & 68 & 3 & 36 & 69 & 4 & 37 & 70 & 5 & 38 & 71 & 6 & 39 & 72 & 7 & 40 & 73 & 8 & 41 & 74 & 9 & 42 & 75 & 10 & 43 & 76 & 11 & 44 & 77\\
\hline
W(3,34) & 2 & 36 & 70 & 3 & 37 & 71 & 4 & 38 & 72 & 5 & 39 & 73 & 6 & 40 & 74 & 7 & 41 & 75 & 8 & 42 & 76 & 9 & 43 & 77 & 10 & 44 & 78 & 11 & 45 & 79\\
\hline
W(3,35) & 2 & 37 & 72 & 3 & 38 & 73 & 4 & 39 & 74 & 5 & 40 & 75 & 6 & 41 & 76 & 7 & 42 & 77 & 8 & 43 & 78 & 9 & 44 & 79 & 10 & 45 & 80 & 11 & 46 & 81\\
\hline
W(3,36) & 2 & 38 & 74 & 3 & 39 & 75 & 4 & 40 & 76 & 5 & 41 & 77 & 6 & 42 & 78 & 7 & 43 & 79 & 8 & 44 & 80 & 9 & 45 & 81 & 10 & 46 & 82 & 11 & 47 & 83\\
\hline
W(3,37) & 2 & 39 & 76 & 3 & 40 & 77 & 4 & 41 & 78 & 5 & 42 & 79 & 6 & 43 & 80 & 7 & 44 & 81 & 8 & 45 & 82 & 9 & 46 & 83 & 10 & 47 & 84 & 11 & 48 & 85\\
\hline
W(3,38) & 2 & 40 & 78 & 3 & 41 & 79 & 4 & 42 & 80 & 5 & 43 & 81 & 6 & 44 & 82 & 7 & 45 & 83 & 8 & 46 & 84 & 9 & 47 & 85 & 10 & 48 & 86 & 11 & 49 & 87\\
\hline
W(3,39) & 2 & 41 & 80 & 3 & 42 & 81 & 4 & 43 & 82 & 5 & 44 & 83 & 6 & 45 & 84 & 7 & 46 & 85 & 8 & 47 & 86 & 9 & 48 & 87 & 10 & 49 & 88 & 11 & 50 & 89\\
\hline
W(3,40) & 2 & 42 & 82 & 3 & 43 & 83 & 4 & 44 & 84 & 5 & 45 & 85 & 6 & 46 & 86 & 7 & 47 & 87 & 8 & 48 & 88 & 9 & 49 & 89 & 10 & 50 & 90 & 11 & 51 & 91\\
\hline
W(3,41) & 2 & 43 & 84 & 3 & 44 & 85 & 4 & 45 & 86 & 5 & 46 & 87 & 6 & 47 & 88 & 7 & 48 & 89 & 8 & 49 & 90 & 9 & 50 & 91 & 10 & 51 & 92 & 11 & 52 & 93\\
\hline
W(3,42) & 2 & 44 & 86 & 3 & 45 & 87 & 4 & 46 & 88 & 5 & 47 & 89 & 6 & 48 & 90 & 7 & 49 & 91 & 8 & 50 & 92 & 9 & 51 & 93 & 10 & 52 & 94 & 11 & 53 & 95\\
\hline
W(3,43) & 2 & 45 & 88 & 3 & 46 & 89 & 4 & 47 & 90 & 5 & 48 & 91 & 6 & 49 & 92 & 7 & 50 & 93 & 8 & 51 & 94 & 9 & 52 & 95 & 10 & 53 & 96 & 11 & 54 & 97\\
\hline
W(3,44) & 2 & 46 & 90 & 3 & 47 & 91 & 4 & 48 & 92 & 5 & 49 & 93 & 6 & 50 & 94 & 7 & 51 & 95 & 8 & 52 & 96 & 9 & 53 & 97 & 10 & 54 & 98 & 11 & 55 & 99\\
\hline
W(3,45) & 2 & 47 & 92 & 3 & 48 & 93 & 4 & 49 & 94 & 5 & 50 & 95 & 6 & 51 & 96 & 7 & 52 & 97 & 8 & 53 & 98 & 9 & 54 & 99 & 10 & 55 & 100 & 11 & 56 & 101\\
\hline
W(3,46) & 2 & 48 & 94 & 3 & 49 & 95 & 4 & 50 & 96 & 5 & 51 & 97 & 6 & 52 & 98 & 7 & 53 & 99 & 8 & 54 & 100 & 9 & 55 & 101 & 10 & 56 & 102 & 11 & 57 & 103\\
\hline
W(3,47) & 2 & 49 & 96 & 3 & 50 & 97 & 4 & 51 & 98 & 5 & 52 & 99 & 6 & 53 & 100 & 7 & 54 & 101 & 8 & 55 & 102 & 9 & 56 & 103 & 10 & 57 & 104 & 11 & 58 & 105\\
\hline
W(3,48) & 2 & 50 & 98 & 3 & 51 & 99 & 4 & 52 & 100 & 5 & 53 & 101 & 6 & 54 & 102 & 7 & 55 & 103 & 8 & 56 & 104 & 9 & 57 & 105 & 10 & 58 & 106 & 11 & 59 & 107\\
\hline
W(3,49) & 2 & 51 & 100 & 3 & 52 & 101 & 4 & 53 & 102 & 5 & 54 & 103 & 6 & 55 & 104 & 7 & 56 & 105 & 8 & 57 & 106 & 9 & 58 & 107 & 10 & 59 & 108 & 11 & 60 & 109\\
\hline
W(3,50) & 2 & 52 & 102 & 3 & 53 & 103 & 4 & 54 & 104 & 5 & 55 & 105 & 6 & 56 & 106 & 7 & 57 & 107 & 8 & 58 & 108 & 9 & 59 & 109 & 10 & 60 & 110 & 11 & 61 & 111\\
\hline
W(3,51) & 2 & 53 & 104 & 3 & 54 & 105 & 4 & 55 & 106 & 5 & 56 & 107 & 6 & 57 & 108 & 7 & 58 & 109 & 8 & 59 & 110 & 9 & 60 & 111 & 10 & 61 & 112 & 11 & 62 & 113\\
\hline
W(3,52) & 2 & 54 & 106 & 3 & 55 & 107 & 4 & 56 & 108 & 5 & 57 & 109 & 6 & 58 & 110 & 7 & 59 & 111 & 8 & 60 & 112 & 9 & 61 & 113 & 10 & 62 & 114 & 11 & 63 & 115\\
\hline
W(3,53) & 2 & 55 & 108 & 3 & 56 & 109 & 4 & 57 & 110 & 5 & 58 & 111 & 6 & 59 & 112 & 7 & 60 & 113 & 8 & 61 & 114 & 9 & 62 & 115 & 10 & 63 & 116 & 11 & 64 & 117\\
\hline
W(3,54) & 2 & 56 & 110 & 3 & 57 & 111 & 4 & 58 & 112 & 5 & 59 & 113 & 6 & 60 & 114 & 7 & 61 & 115 & 8 & 62 & 116 & 9 & 63 & 117 & 10 & 64 & 118 & 11 & 65 & 119\\
\hline
W(3,55) & 2 & 57 & 112 & 3 & 58 & 113 & 4 & 59 & 114 & 5 & 60 & 115 & 6 & 61 & 116 & 7 & 62 & 117 & 8 & 63 & 118 & 9 & 64 & 119 & 10 & 65 & 120 & 11 & 66 & 121\\
\hline
W(3,56) & 2 & 58 & 114 & 3 & 59 & 115 & 4 & 60 & 116 & 5 & 61 & 117 & 6 & 62 & 118 & 7 & 63 & 119 & 8 & 64 & 120 & 9 & 65 & 121 & 10 & 66 & 122 & 11 & 67 & 123\\
\hline
W(3,57) & 2 & 59 & 116 & 3 & 60 & 117 & 4 & 61 & 118 & 5 & 62 & 119 & 6 & 63 & 120 & 7 & 64 & 121 & 8 & 65 & 122 & 9 & 66 & 123 & 10 & 67 & 124 & 11 & 68 & 125\\
\hline
W(3,58) & 2 & 60 & 118 & 3 & 61 & 119 & 4 & 62 & 120 & 5 & 63 & 121 & 6 & 64 & 122 & 7 & 65 & 123 & 8 & 66 & 124 & 9 & 67 & 125 & 10 & 68 & 126 & 11 & 69 & 127\\
\hline
W(3,59) & 2 & 61 & 120 & 3 & 62 & 121 & 4 & 63 & 122 & 5 & 64 & 123 & 6 & 65 & 124 & 7 & 66 & 125 & 8 & 67 & 126 & 9 & 68 & 127 & 10 & 69 & 128 & 11 & 70 & 129\\
\hline
W(3,60) & 2 & 62 & 122 & 3 & 63 & 123 & 4 & 64 & 24 & 5 & 65 & 125 & 6 & 66 & 126 & 7 & 67 & 127 & 8 & 68 & 128 & 9 & 69 & 128 & 10 & 70 & 130 & 11 & 71 & 131\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}%
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]